# user data is NOT saved to its databse

Tags: php, html, mysql

I am new to PHP and i am trying to built a registration form for users and to saved user input to  database, but user data are not saving to database. Someone please help !

cofiguration.php

```
<?php
define('HOST','localhost');
define('USER','root');
define('PASSWORD_HOST','');
define('DATABASE','test_db');
if (defined('HOST') && defined('USER') && defined('PASSWORD_HOST') && defined('DATABASE')){
    $conn=mysqli_connect(HOST,USER,PASSWORD_HOST,DATABASE);
}else{
    die("connection failed:" .mysqli_connect_error());
}
?>
```

here i am updating my whole index.php file.

index.php

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<style>
.error {color: #FF0000;}
</style>
<?php
require_once "configuration.php";


//set trigger for login form
        $registereduserValidInput=true;


if (isset($_POST['RegisterSubmitButton']))
                {

                            //if firstname field is empty
                             if (empty($_POST["firstname"]))
                            {
                                  $firstnameErr="Let us know your first name";
                                  $registereduserValidInput=false;

                            }else
                            {
                              $firstname = test_input($_POST["firstname"]);
                              if (!preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z ]*$/",$firstname))
                              {
                                  $firstnameErr1="please provide letters only";
                                  $registereduserValidInput=false;
                              }
                            }



        /*.................................................................................................
        ...................................................................................................*/

                     //if last name field is empty
                      if (empty($_POST["lastname"]))
                      {
                          $lastnameErr="Please provide last name";
                          $registereduserValidInput=false;
                      }else
                      {
                          $lastname=test_input($_POST["lastname"]);
                            if (!preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z ]*$/",$lastname))
                            {
                              $lastnameErr1="Please provide letters only";
                              $registereduserValidInput=false;
                            }
                      }

        /*.................................................................................................
        ...................................................................................................*/
                     //check email field

                      if (empty($_POST["useremail"]))
                        {
                            $emailErrA = "Email is required";
                            $registereduserValidInput = false;
                        }else 
                        {
                            $email = test_input($_POST["useremail"]);
                              //email validation
                            if (!filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL))
                                {      
                                        $emailErr1A = "Invalid email format";
                                }
                        }

        /*.................................................................................................
        ...................................................................................................*/
                    //check password field

                     if(empty($_POST["userpassword"]))
                    {
                            $passwordErr="Password is required";
                            $registereduserValidInput = false;
                    }else {
                            $password = test_input($_POST["userpassword"]);
                          }      

        /*.................................................................................................
         ...................................................................................................*/ 
                     //password verification field

                     if(empty($_POST["verifypassword"]))
                     {
                            $verifypasswordErr="Re-enter your Password";
                            $registereduserValidInput = false;
                     }else {
                            $verifypassword = test_input($_POST["verifypassword"]);
                           }

         /*.................................................................................................
         ...................................................................................................*/      
                    //script to check whether the two password fields matches or not



                        if (strcmp($password, $verifypassword) !== 0)
                        {
                            $passwordnotmatch="Password do no match";       //if passwords do not match generate error to user 
                            $registereduserValidInput = false;
                        }else {
                                  $passwordmatch="password match";      
                              }

         /*.................................................................................................
        ...................................................................................................*/




         /*.................................................................................................
         ...................................................................................................*/ 
                    // if all inputs are provided by user run sql query to check whether email is already registered or not

                    if($registereduserValidInput==true){





                     $sql1=mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT * FROM registereduser WHERE useremail='$_POST[email]'");
                     $rows1 = mysqli_num_rows($sql1);

                            if($rows1==0)
                            {
                               //insert user input to "registeredUser" table


                               $sqlTable ="INSERT INTO registereduser (firstname, lastname, useremail, userpassword) VALUES ('".$firstname."', '".$lastname."', '".$email."','".$password."')";
                               mysqli_query($conn, $sqlTable);
                                }else{
                                     echo "This email ID is already registered with us. kindly login again!";
                                     die;
                                 }
                    }
      }
?>

<body>




<form method="post" action="index.php">
                                <h2>Registration Form</h2><br><br>
                                Enter Your First Nmae:<br><br>
                                <input type="text" name="firstname"  placeholder="First Name" value="">
                                                     <span class="error"> <?php echo $firstnameErr; ?> </span>
                                                     <span class="error"> <?php echo $firstnameErr1; ?> </span><br><br>
                                Enter Your Last Name:<br><br>

                                <input type="text" name="lastname"  placeholder="Last Name" value="">
                                                     <span class="error"> <?php echo $lastnameErr; ?> </span>
                                                     <span class="error"> <?php echo $lastnameErr1; ?> </span><br><br>

                                Enter Your Email:<br><br>

                                <input type="text" name="useremail" value="" >
                                                     <span class="error"> <?php echo $emailErrA;?></span>
                                                     <span class="error"> <?php echo $emailErr1A;?></span><br><br>
                                Enter Your Password:<br><br>

                                <input type="password" name="userpassword" value="">

                                                    <span class="error"> <?php echo $passwordErr;?></span><br><br>
                                Re-enter Your Password:<br><br>

                                <input type="password" name="verifypassword" value="">

                                                    <span class="error"> <?php echo $verifypasswordErr;?></span>
                                                    <span class="error"> <?php echo $passwordmatch;?></span><br><br>
                                <input type="submit" name="RegisterSubmitButton" value="Click here to Register">
                                </form>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Get rid off single quotes in table and column names in `'registereduser' ('firstname', 'lastname', 'useremail','userpassword')`

Comment: the connection comes FIRST, not LAST. that's for one, the other one's not even being executed while using the wrong identifiers

Comment: Why are you testing whether the constants are defined instead of testing whether `mysqli_connect()` succeeded?

Comment: sure hoping this is for education purposes only and not meant to go live

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code to perform the database query and insert should be:

```
    if($registereduserValidInput==true){
        $sql1=mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT * FROM registereduser WHERE useremail='$_POST[email]'") or die(mysqli_error($conn));
        $rows1 = mysqli_num_rows($sql1);
        if($rows1==0)
            {
                //insert user input to "registeredUser" table


                $sqlTable ="INSERT INTO registereduser (firstname, lastname, useremail,userpassword) VALUES ('".$firstname."', '".$lastname."', '".$email."','".$password."')";
                mysqli_query($conn, $sqlTable) or die(mysqli_error($conn));
            }else{
            echo "This email ID is already registered with us. kindly login again!";
            die;
        }
    }
```

You were missing the `$conn` argument in the `SELECT` query (you had the variable at the end of the SQL instead), and you never called `mysqli_query()` on `$sqlTable`.

You should also look up how to use prepared statements and `bind_param`. Substituting variables into a query leaves you open to SQL injection.

Comment: I have tried with your code, but its not working! :(

Comment: Try it now with the error checking I added. Is it reporting an error?

Comment: I have tried with error checking code as    error_reporting(E_ALL & ~E_NOTICE & ~E_DEPRECATED & ~E_WARNING);     but it is not reporting any error.

Comment: That won't report SQL errors. You need to add `or die(mysqli_error($conn))` like I did.

Comment: I have updated the whole index.php file. please go through it once , i am in big problem sir :(

Comment: Use `error_reporting(E_ALL)`. You should enable warnings so you get messages about undefined variables.

Answer (score 0):

Few error I have found..

1. No field for password in Form or any variable for $password.
2. Not getting any method name **test_input**
3. ```
   $sql1=mysqli_query("SELECT * FROM registereduser WHERE useremail='$_POST[email]',$conn");
       should be like
   $sql1=mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT * FROM mdm_users WHERE school_name='$_POST[useremail]'");
   ```
4. and Most

   ```
   $sqlTable ="INSERT INTO 'registereduser' ('firstname', 'lastname', 'useremail','userpassword') VALUES ('".$firstname."', '".$lastname."', '".$email."','".$password."')";
   ```

line should be like

```
    $sqlTable ="INSERT INTO registereduser (firstname, lastname, useremail,userpassword) VALUES ('".$firstname."', '".$lastname."', '".$email."','".$password."')";
    mysqli_query($conn, $sqlTable);
```

please remove the single quotes in table and column names.

Comment: here i am posting my whole index.php

Comment: In the condition.. if (strcmp($Password, $verifypassword) !== 0) .. please change $Password to $password..

Comment: whatever input i  entered its showing "This email ID is already registered with us. kindly login again!" :(

Comment: You have to enter different email id in every registration.

Comment: Yes, i am trying with different email id in every registration, but its showing the same.moreover user data is not saving to database